# Elastic effect to an object?

Tags: ios, animation

I want to make an object that will move in a elastic way when I pan it around. The best example I could find was this GIF I made from the game PapiRubber:

http://imgflip.com/i/3vsmg  (Please excuse the quality)

If you note the rubber band looking rectangle stretching about, that is what I am trying to implement in my application!

I don't really know where to begin where to start making something like that except asking for help :]

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7, there is a new subset of [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html) called UIKit Dynamics. UIKit Dynamics allows assigning behaviors such as springs and gravity to view objects, so you get physics behaviors without writing a lot of code.

The best way to get started is to watch the [WWDC 2013 videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/). These sessions cover UIKit dynamics:

- 206: Getting Started with UIKit Dynamics
- 221: Advanced Techniques with UIKit Dynamics

Apple provides a code example called [UIKit Dynamics Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) which you can download and try.

Comment: Awesome! Does this mean that any device running IOS 7 will be able to access my application?